# deis-builder service have error when I provision Deis with Vagrant on CoreOS

Tags: vagrant, docker, coreos, deis

I'm using Vagrant to provision Deis on local machines with CoreOS. I'm following the official instructions of [CoreOS section](https://github.com/deis/deis#boot-coreos).

The problem was presented when I execute command line: `make run`,specifically on step to deploy **deis-builder.service**, the status output it's:

```
● deis-builder.service - deis-builder
   Loaded: loaded (/run/fleet/units/deis-builder.service; linked-runtime)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2014-08-21 09:11:59 UTC; 24min ago
  Process: 2726 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c IMAGE=`/run/deis/bin/get_image /deis/builder` && docker run --name deis-builder --rm -p 2223:22 -e HTTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY -e http_proxy=$http_proxy -e HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY -e https_proxy=$https_proxy -e ALL_PROXY=$ALL_PROXY -e all_proxy=$all_proxy -e NO_PROXY=$NO_PROXY -e no_proxy=$no_proxy -e PUBLISH=22 -e HOST=$COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4 -e PORT=2223 --volumes-from deis-builder-data --privileged $IMAGE (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2716 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c docker inspect deis-builder >/dev/null 2>&1 && docker rm -f deis-builder || true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2685 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c IMAGE=`/run/deis/bin/get_image /deis/builder`; docker history $IMAGE >/dev/null 2>&1 || docker pull $IMAGE (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2726 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 2727 (sh)
   CGroup: /system.slice/deis-builder.service
           └─control
             ├─2727 /bin/sh -c echo 'Waiting for builder on 2223/tcp...' && until cat </dev/null>/dev/tcp/$COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4/2223; do sleep 1; done
             └─5875 sleep 1

Aug 21 09:36:22 deis-3 sh[2727]: /bin/sh: connect: Connection refused
Aug 21 09:36:22 deis-3 sh[2727]: /bin/sh: /dev/tcp/172.17.8.102/2223: Connection refused
Aug 21 09:36:23 deis-3 sh[2727]: /bin/sh: connect: Connection refused
Aug 21 09:36:23 deis-3 sh[2727]: /bin/sh: /dev/tcp/172.17.8.102/2223: Connection refused
Aug 21 09:36:24 deis-3 sh[2727]: /bin/sh: connect: Connection refused
Aug 21 09:36:24 deis-3 sh[2727]: /bin/sh: /dev/tcp/172.17.8.102/2223: Connection refused
Aug 21 09:36:25 deis-3 sh[2727]: /bin/sh: connect: Connection refused
Aug 21 09:36:25 deis-3 sh[2727]: /bin/sh: /dev/tcp/172.17.8.102/2223: Connection refused
Aug 21 09:36:26 deis-3 sh[2727]: /bin/sh: connect: Connection refused
Aug 21 09:36:26 deis-3 sh[2727]: /bin/sh: /dev/tcp/172.17.8.102/2223: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was created as a [deis issue-1664](https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/1664), and explanation was provided for @carmstrong. In summary the main problem it's slow Internet connection and time out when deis/builder execute `docker pull slugbuilder` on bin/boot script. For more specification, please look at [deis issue-1664](https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/1664).